# Simple post to db in php/mysql - edit

Tags: php, mysql, post

Pretty simple stuff, I know, but am getting an error

```
<?php  
session_start();  

$dbhost = "###"; // this will ususally be 'localhost', but can sometimes differ  
$dbname = "###"; // the name of the database that you are going to use for this project  
$dbuser = "###"; // the username that you created, or were given, to access your database  
$dbpass = "###"; // the password that you created, or were given, to access your database  

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  

mysql_select_db("###", $con);

$safe_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$sql="INSERT INTO register (email) VALUES ('{$safe_email}')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: Also, some suggested reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: -0.49 for still using `mysql_query`.  As it is, you have an SQL injection vulnerability that wouldn't even be possible if you were using prepared statements (well, using them properly).

Comment: No error displayed. I am admittedly a hack at this and have really only used some plug and play php for sending emails. This is just too simple a script to find, so I took a swing and missed.

Comment: OK, i have to ask.  Can we safely assume you actually *have* a table named "register", with a field named "email" and no keys aside from the email and/or an auto-increment primary key?

Comment: I can safely assume, as I was told, that 'email' went into 'register' and it has an auto increment.

Comment: So, you don't have any access to the database or it's schema??

Comment: Unfortunately not. For all I currently know, he may be mistaken. Towards that end, I guess I'm just asking if the code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following:

1. You don't have a lot of experience with PHP
2. The information that has been provided to you is correct
3. This is an example script and you know the values that need to be substituted for `$dbname`, `$dbhost`, `$dbuser` and `$dbpass`

Please try the following and report back if you get any output at all to screen:

```
    <?php  
    session_start();  

    print "Connecting and inserting email: ".$_POST['email']."...";

    $dbhost = "###"; // this will ususally be 'localhost', but can sometimes differ  
    $dbname = "###"; // the name of the database that you are going to use for this project  
    $dbuser = "###"; // the username that you created, or were given, to access your database  
    $dbpass = "###"; // the password that you created, or were given, to access your database  

    $con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  

    $safe_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO register (email) VALUES ('{$safe_email}')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    print "success! Inserted email with row id: ".mysql_insert_id();

    mysql_close($con)
    ?>
```

Comment: got the following: Connecting and inserting email: ...success! I guess I can get rid of the 'print' command line?

Comment: @Adam I made a small change just to confirm it is working. In your original post you said there was an auto increment on the table. Try running a few tests and make sure the number output in the success message is in fact increasing. Then you know for definite it's working and you can remove the print statements...

Comment: I was able to talk with the client and he has confirmed that the records are being added. Thanks again from a PHP noob. I promise to learn more...

Answer (score 2):

`$con` is not defined anywhere in your code, before you use it in the query call. You should have:

```
$con = mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

Beyond that, your code is WIDE open to SQL injection attacks. You should have:

```
$safe_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$sql="INSERT INTO register (email) VALUES ('{$safe_email}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

this may just be me but you should but strings on a single line or use the concatenation (.) for the strings

```
$sql="INSERT INTO register (email) VALUES ('$_POST[email]')";
```

Other than that you should clean the information before adding it into the database otherwise your asking for sql injection attacks.

now to the actual problem. your using a variable that is undefined called conn. i am assuming your referencing the connection made, but you never set that variable to the connection like so

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dblocal,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die(xxx);
```

Comment: I prefer strings on multiple lines (*without* `.`) for non-trivial SQL.  Otherwise, PHP's grammar gets in my way.